# Why am I getting this segmentation fault in my code while iterating through large quantities of int values?

Tags: c

The C program I am trying to write is meant to take a file of integer values and sum the first number with the second, then the first with the third, the first with the forth, and so on. Then sum the second with the third, the second with the forth, and so on. It is also meant to print a message whenever a predetermined value is met while adding all the numbers (in my case, it's 10), and print out the time it took for this program to execute.

However, when the program starts going through the list of integers in the file I am taking values from (over 10,000 integers are in this file), it seems that it gets to the 124th loop and then gives me a Segmentation Fault (Core Dumped) error. When I reduce the number of integers to be added to under 124, the program works fine.

Why am I getting this Segmentation Fault error? Is it in the way that I set up my While loops? Is there any way I can remedy this?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
int main(){
   FILE *fptr1,*fptr2,*temp;
   fptr1 = fopen("input.txt", "r") ;
  
   int num1,num2;
   int sum=0;
   int c=0;
  
   if (fptr1 == NULL) {
       printf("File not open\n");
       return 0;;
   }
   int count=0;
  
   clock_t t;
t = clock();


// the problem seems to be in this while loop//

while(fscanf(fptr1, "%d", &num1) !=EOF){
       count++;
       fptr2 = fopen("input.txt", "r") ;
       int count1=0;
       while(fscanf(fptr2, "%d", &num2) !=EOF){
           count1++;
           if(count1>count){
               sum=num1+num2;
               if(sum==10){c++;}
           }
       }
      
   }
   
printf("sum of 10 was found in %d iterations of loop",c);
t = clock() - t;
double time_taken = ((double)t)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC; // in seconds
  
printf("Time taken :%lf", time_taken);

  
   fclose(fptr1);
   fclose(fptr2);
   return 0;
}
```

When the file has over 124 integers, it gives me this:
[the output when over 124 integers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BibEA.png)

and when he file has less than 124 integers, it gives me this:
[the output when under 124 integers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nis3O.png)

Comment: Use a debugger to find out exactly which line of code triggers the seg fault and update your post with that info. Then continue using the debugger to step thru the code and examine the state as it runs to help you diagnose the problem.

Comment: Tip: Declare your variables just before they're used, not in a heap at the top of your functions. This makes it way easier to understand what you're doing in your code.

Comment: ⟼This code could benefit greatly by adopting an [indentation style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) and applying it consistently. Indentation conveys structure and intent which makes it easier for us to understand your code without having to invest a lot of time deciphering it, and it can also make mistakes more obvious as they stand out visually.

Comment: You seem to be calling `fopen` inside a loop and not closing those handles. It may mean your process is unable to open more files until some are closed. **Always check the return value of functions before using the result**.

Comment: Whats the point of calling ***fopen*** in a loop? Since the filename doesnt change, you could call it once at the beginning of your function and also check for NULL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem seems to be opening way too many file handles, but the fix should be simple:

```c
while(fscanf(fptr1, "%d", &num1) !=EOF){
  count++;

  // This fopen() call might fail, you should check the result
  fptr2 = fopen("input.txt", "r");

  int count1 = 0;

  while(fscanf(fptr2, "%d", &num2) != EOF) {
    // ...
  }

  // If you open a file, you must close it before re-opening
  fclose(fptr2);
}
```

This is quite wasteful, though, there's no reason to open over and over, instead
just rewind the file and use it again:

```c
fptr2 = fopen("input.txt", "r");

while(fscanf(fptr1, "%d", &num1) !=EOF) {
  // Move back to the beginning of the file before reading
  rewind(fptr2);

  count++;

  int count1 = 0;

  while(fscanf(fptr2, "%d", &num2) != EOF) {
    // ...
  }
}

fclose(fptr2);
```

> Another thing to note here is your variable names are extremely opaque. `fptr2` doesn't communicate anything about what this is supposed to be used for, or what that file might contain. If it correlates with an input source, consider `input` or `finput` or even `fin`. Likewise, `count1` and `count` and an even more mysterious `c` are confusing. Counting what? For what reason?